# Doing {a time between midnight and 1am} .isBefore {a time later that day} is coming up FALSE (it seems) - using moment-timezone

Tags: node.js, dst, moment-timezone

I'm trying to replicate a bug. Essentially, I've got the code below in an app. It works here i.e. 'midnight is before 7am' is true.

```
// The server is running in UTC

const moment = require("moment-timezone");
moment.tz.setDefault("Europe/London");

const now = moment("2020-04-20 00:00"); // In the app, 'now' is the current moment()

const testTime = "07:00", testTimeMoment = moment(testTime, "HH:mm");

console.log(`now: ${now}\nUTC: ${now.utc()}\ntestTime: ${testTimeMoment}`);
console.log(`'now' is before 'testTime' ? ${now.isBefore(testTimeMoment)}`);
```

The console.log is:

> now: Mon Apr 20 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0100
>
> UTC: Sun Apr 19 2020 23:00:00 GMT+0000
>
> testTime: Mon Apr 20 2020 07:00:00 GMT+0100
>
> 'now' is before 'testTime' ? true

But in my app this test seems to fail, until you get to 1am and later, and then the comparison becomes true.

My server here in the UK is running on UTC/GMT. But we're on daylight saving time, so I'm defaulting to London time.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE:** The comparison operator is actually behaving correctly. It's not giving the expected result because, between midnight and 1am, the testTime moment is created as 7am **the day before**. It's 7am British Summer Time as I want it, because of setting the default timezone at the top of the code, **but the day before**. After 1am, the moment is correctly created as 7am today.